# Что значат 2 набора скобок при обращении к классу в python?

Tags: python, классы, методы, tensorflow, keras

Например:

```
x = layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation="relu")(x)
```

Или это:

```
x = layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
```

Никак не могу понять что это за `(x)` передается и чему в конце

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего тут ситуация, когда функция возвращает в качестве результата другую функцию. И вот эта функция-результат потом вызывается с аргументом. На этом же принципе построены **декораторы** в питоне. Простейший пример:

```py
def func(a):
  def f(x):
    return a+x
  return f

print(func(1)(2))
print(func(42))
```

Вывод:

```
3
<function func.<locals>.f at 0x7fafb43a2050>
```

Как видим, `func(...)` возвращает функцию, а `func(...)(...)` возвращает результат работы этой функции. В принципе, такие цепочки могут быть и длиннее, чем два звена.